Jersey/JAXB 3 and Jakarta SAXParseException
I've migrated our old Jersey 2.39/javax application to Jersey/JAXB 3.1.9 and jakarta 10 (Tomcat 10.1).
The GET endpoints are working ok.  However, PUT/POST endpoints all fail.
The error is:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.]
The XML payloads are identically to what worked previously in Tomcat 9/Jersey 2.  The first line of each XML payload is:
I've also tried adding a servlet filter to remove hidden BOM but that didn't work
Looking for tips.

I added a filter to see what JAXB was taking as input.  Somehow, "<<<" is being appended to the input stream.  So it is trying to process, "<<<..."
I have another filter that logs the input steram to the database and it does not have those extra characters.  So something is addding them before JAXB can do its thing

I bumped jakarta.xml.bind-api to 4.0.2 and jaxb-runtime to 4.0.05 and the issue was fixed
